# How to enumerate dates into a Google Sheets' column?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-cell-format

I need to enumerate a Google Sheets' column with consecutive business dates (Sunday-Thursday) starting and ending with specific days.

Can this be done automatically or I have to this manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Manual way:

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
```

[image]

## Automatic way:

```
2.7
3.7
4.7
5.7
6.7
7.7
8.7
```

- enter dates in cells
- select all cells
- go to: **Format** > **Number** > **More Formats** > **More date and time formats...**
- delete: **.<kbd>Month (8)</kbd>**
- hit those arrows next to **<kbd>Day (5)</kbd>**
- from dropdown menu select: **Day as full name (Tuesday)**
- press **<kbd>Apply</kbd>** button and you are done

[image]